# jQuery how to generate code inside code?

Tags: jquery, json, load, document.write

my question might be a bit confusing, but here is what i would like to do.
i have a script:

```
<script>
   ...some script here...
    var audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2", [
    {
        name:"Lismore",
        mp3:"http://example.com/song.mp3"
    },
    {
        name:"The Separation",
        mp3:"http://example.com/song1.mp3"
    }
 ])
</script>
```

what i would like to do is to generate that script dynamically using $.get.JSON

```
var audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2", [
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/users', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
document.write(name: ''item.fname'',)
document.write(mp3: "http://example.com/"''+item.song_id+''".mp3")
}):
});
])
```

inside the `<script>`

is this possible? i've tried the script and it fails.

Comment: don not really undrestand your question.. do you need to recieve the playlist content from server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be possible to generate code dynamically to do that, but there is no reason to do that.

Just use the `map` method to convert the array of data that you get from the AJAX call into the form that you need for the `Playlist` object:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/users', function(data) {
  var items = $.map(data, function(item) {
    return { name: item.fname, mp3: "http://example.com/" + item.song_id + ".mp3" };
  });
  var audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2", items);
});
```

Comment: looks like it's working.. i get some `undefined` errors, but i'm sure that is a JSON problem. thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

//Note: getJSON call is asynchronous, unless the ajaxSettings are modified to make it synchronous and hence audioPlaylist variable is assigned a value only after the callback of getJSON is completed.

```
 var audioPlaylist = null; 
 $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/users', function(data) {
    var playData = [];
  $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        playData.push({
            name:item.fname, 
            mp3: "http://example.com/" + item.song_id + ".mp3"
        });
        audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2", playData);
         alert(audioPlaylist);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//Song Object
function Song(name, mp3){
  this.name = name;
  this.mp3 = mp3;
}

//Create array of Song objects
var songs = new Array();

//Populate it from the AJAX call
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/users', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(i,item) {
       songs.push(new Song(item.fname, "http://example.com/" + item.song_id + ".mp3"));
   }):
});

//build the Playlist Object
var audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2",songs);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is best if you're trying to update the data.  If you actually want to write scripts to the page, first get the script text assembled and then do something simple like:

```
$('body').append("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('hello world');<\/script>");
```